# Is adb pull of same command (same data) will overwrote, appended, or skipped?

Tags: adb

I tried `adb pull foo/folder baz/folder` twice. But during pulling (first attempt), I interrupt (cancel it with ctrl+c) the process, then I tried the same command again (second attempt), it continues pulling but I have no idea will it overwrite, appending (duplicate), or skipping the existing data?

Comment: I would assume that on file level it overwrites and on folder level it simply adds new/not yet existing files. For working with folders you may have a look onto https://github.com/jb2170/better-adb-sync which is a fork of Google's adb-sync project.

Comment: @Robert how to copy the folder without overwrite and appended? What command and option shall I do with `better-adb-sync` I expect it skips existing data.